# Can't get the current URL of recent web page in android

Tags: java, android

How to get the current URL of the current web page? I have tried with `geturl()` and  `getoriginalurl()` but to no success.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
             // Where url is your current url.
                return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
            }
        });
```

Comment: bro thanx a ton...really um greatfull to u :)

Comment: @user3917293 There is a right mark near my answer click on it.